# Trying to set font size of header tag via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a twitter feed control and I'm trying to adjust the font size of one of the elements using javascript.

Here's the html snippet in question:

```
 <div class="twtr-hd">
     <a class="twtr-profile-img-anchor" href="http://twitter.com/pikefindotcom" target="_blank"><img src="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1266884773/stock-market-chart_normal.jpg" class="twtr-profile-img" alt="profile"></a>                     
    <h3>Pikefin</h3>    
        <h4><a href="http://twitter.com/pikefindotcom" target="_blank">pikefindotcom</a></h4> 
</div>
```

I'm trying to change the font size of this tag:

```
<h3>Pikefin</h3>
```

Here's the Firebug output that is showing the appropriate css:

```
#twtr-widget-1 .twtr-doc, #twtr-widget-1 .twtr-hd a, #twtr-widget-1 h3, #twtr-widget-1 h4, #twtr-widget-1 .twtr-popular {
    background-color: #333333 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
index.php #4 (line 1)
.twtr-widget h3 {
    font-size: 11px !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
widget.css (line 12)
.twtr-widget-profile h3, .twtr-widget-profile h4 {
    margin: 0 0 0 40px !important;
}
widget.css (line 12)
```

I'm using jquery to retrieve the element (disclaimer: jquery noob) which seems to work fine but then I can't figure out the syntax to set the font size. 
Here's what I thought the code *should* be:

```
var element = $('.twtr-hdr h3');
element.style.fontSize="17px";
```

But that gives me this error message:
"element.style is undefined"

So I'm unsure as to exactly what object type jquery is returning. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use jQuery's `.css`:

```
$(".twtr-hdr h3").css({fontSize:"17px"});
```

Your code doesn't work because jQuery doesn't return the actual element, it returns an array...so:

```
element[0].style... //this should work too
```

Answer (score 3):

this should be,

`$('.twtr-hdr h3').css("font-size", "17px");`

Comment: same as 2 other answers before yours

Comment: that is because I have less then 125 reps. so I can't post another answer in 3 mins. :( Also this works!

Comment: well, someone seems to like it ;) +1

Comment: @hunter, thanks, I hope I will earn 20 more reps so I can answer fast next time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
var element = $('.twtr-hdr h3').get(0); // this way you'll get the javascript object
element.style.fontSize="17px";
```

or:

```
$('.twtr-hdr h3').attr("style", "font-size: 17px"); // jQuery style
```